# How to make tags for each select unique in vue-multiselect

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have a custom dropdown created using `vue-multiselect`. It should be a simple dropdown that lists the selected choices as tags. It works, but when I add other dropdowns the selected tags in one dropdown appear in all of the rest. How can I make so that each dropdown shows only the selected options for it without filling the other dropdowns?

Here is my code:

```
 <multiselect
         v-model="value"
             tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
             placeholder="Assesors"
             label="name"
             track-by="code"
             :options="options"
             :multiple="true"
             :taggable="true"
   ></multiselect>


 <multiselect
         v-model="value"
             tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
             placeholder="Assesors"
             label="name"
             track-by="code"
             :options="options"
             :multiple="true"
             :taggable="true"
   ></multiselect>


 <multiselect
         v-model="value"
             tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
             placeholder="Assesors"
             label="name"
             track-by="code"
             :options="options"
             :multiple="true"
             :taggable="true"
   ></multiselect>
```

and my javascript:

```
 data() {
    return {
      showAddUserDialog: false,
       value: [],
       options: [
        { name: "Assesors", code: "as" },
        { name: "Finance", code: "fi" },
        { name: "Sales", code: "sa" },
      ]
    }
  }
```

and a working codepen:

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-tag-example-forked-qecqn

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable "value" as the v-model for the three inputs, which is causing all the selects to show the same selected data.

Try changing to different variables in the v-model (such as value, value1 and value2, for example)  and you will be fine.

```
     <multiselect
         v-model="value"
             tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
             placeholder="Assesors"
             label="name"
             track-by="code"
             :options="options"
             :multiple="true"
             :taggable="true"
   ></multiselect>


 <multiselect
         v-model="value1"
             tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
             placeholder="Assesors"
             label="name"
             track-by="code"
             :options="options"
             :multiple="true"
             :taggable="true"
   ></multiselect>
```

and make sure to add value1 in the js:

```
 data() {
    return {
      showAddUserDialog: false,
       value: [],
       value1: [],
       options: [
        { name: "Assesors", code: "as" },
        { name: "Finance", code: "fi" },
        { name: "Sales", code: "sa" },
      ]
    }
  }
```